# Linking a shared object into other shared object C++ project

Tags: c++, linker, cmake

I am working in a very big C++ project to create a big shared object where we are using an external SDK which have several header files and several shared libraries which belong to each other. This means that the declaration of SDK classes are in the header files but their definitions are in the shared objects.

I understand that because of the declarations in header files I can compile this code.

But what I do not understand exactly is **when do I have to specify the used shared objects for the linker explicitly?**

Namely if I specify it (e.g. in cmake with *target_link_libraries* command) then the linker can check that a symbol will be in the shared library or not. But what happens if I do not specify it (i.e. there is not any -l[shared_object_name] flags in linkage)? My experience is (which surprised me) that is work properly (i.e. the whole building process finished). How can it possible?

Comment: Some compilers, such as Microsoft-VC have a `#pragma` that allows you to specify compiler and linker options in the source code. Boost uses this to automatically select the correct shared library depending on compiler macros.

Comment: We are working with GCC under linux and do not use #pragma :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In POSIX shared libraries, you can have undefined symbols in a shared library, and all will link just fine. As long as the executable is fully linked, there will be no linker errors.

That's done this way because dynamic libraries mimic the behaviour of static libraries, and static libraries can have undefined symbols (static libraries are not linked, to begin with).

If you come from a Windows background, then it will surprise you, because Windows DLLs cannot have undefined symbols.

If you are worried about this, you can check the linker options `--no-undefined` and `--no-allow-shlib-undefined`.

Comment: This means that in the executable it have to be linked both my shared object and the shared object which is used in my shared object? Instead my shared object can not find the body of the used symbol.

Comment: @TiborTakács: Yes. Your shared object isn't _trying_ to find the symbols in the other shared object. That all gets resolved when you build an actual executable.

Comment: @TiborTakács: If the first SO links in the second SO, it will add a `NEEDED` entry in the first SO header, so that when the exe links to the first SO, the second SO will be linked in automatically. But if you link the first SO without the second SO, then the exe will need to link to both  or else it will fail.

Answer (score 2):

> My experience is (which surprised me) that is work properly (i.e. the whole building process finished).

That seems unlikely.

In fact…

> How can it possible?

It's not.

The only explanation is that you *weren't* using symbols defined inside those library files. They were either in header-only parts of the third-party code, or they weren't part of the third-party code at all.

Or you were building a shared library of your own. The ultimate executable would still need the third-party libraries linked in, though.

Comment: I am creating also a shared library. Is this a cause?

Comment: @TiborTakács: Yes. That's a crucial detail that should have been in the question from the start. As it stands, the original final paragraph of my answer is what you're looking for.